# What is the best way to determine a session variable is null or empty in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

What is the best way to check for the existence of a session variable in ASP.NET C#?

I like to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` works for strings and wondered if there was a similar method for `Session`.  Currently the only way I know of is:

```
 var session;
 if (Session["variable"] != null)
 {
     session = Session["variable"].ToString();
 }
 else
 {
     session = "set this";
     Session["variable"] = session;
 }
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To follow on from what others have said. I tend to have two layers:

**The core layer. This is within a DLL that is added to nearly all web app projects**. In this I have a SessionVars class which does the grunt work for Session state getters/setters. It contains code like the following:

```
public class SessionVar
{
    static HttpSessionState Session
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("No Http Context, No Session to Get!");

            return HttpContext.Current.Session;
        }
    }

    public static T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        if (Session[key] == null)
            return default(T);
        else
            return (T)Session[key];
    }

    public static void Set<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        Session[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Note the generics for getting any type.

I then also add Getters/Setters for specific types, especially string since I often prefer to work with string.Empty rather than null for variables presented to Users.

e.g:

```
public static string GetString(string key)
{
    string s = Get<string>(key);
    return s == null ? string.Empty : s;
}

public static void SetString(string key, string value)
{
    Set<string>(key, value);
}
```

And so on...

**I then create wrappers to abstract that away and bring it up to the application model. For example, if we have customer details:**

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return SessionVar.GetString("CustomerInfo_Name");
        }
        set
        {
            SessionVar.SetString("CustomerInfo_Name", value);
        }
    }
}
```

You get the idea right? :)

**NOTE:** Just had a thought when adding a comment to the accepted answer. Always ensure objects are serializable when storing them in Session when using a state server. It can be all too easy to try and save an object using the generics when on  web farm and it go boom. I deploy on a web farm at work so added checks to my code in the core layer to see if the object is serializable, another benefit of encapsulating the Session Getters and Setters :)

Comment: Great approach! I have been using something similar for a long time, but hadn't incorporated generics. This avoids so many problems with different developers creating similar Session variables.

Comment: How can I do for handle exceptions if the " throw new ApplicationException("No Http Context, No Session to Get!");" is executed ?, I am confusing about the Auto-Implemented Properties, In wich part of the code I could get the exception when occurs.

Comment: Nice approach. I'm having trouble implementing this in a C# Class Library. I can't resolve references to `HttpSessionState`/`HttpContext`. Did you have to install the MVC library in the DLL to import the proper namespaces?

Answer (score 20):

That is pretty much how you do it.  However, there is a shorter syntax you can use.

```
sSession = (string)Session["variable"] ?? "set this";
```

This is saying if the session variables is null, set sSession to "set this"

Comment: you can't do this... Session["variable"] is an Object and the compiler will then convert it to a String because sSession is a String, if the Session["variable"] does not exist, it throws an exception!

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I updated the code to cast the string if Session is not null.

Answer (score 14):

It may make things more elegant to wrap it in a property.

```
string MySessionVar
{
   get{
      return Session["MySessionVar"] ?? String.Empty;
   }
   set{
      Session["MySessionVar"] = value;
   }
}
```

then you can treat it as a string.

```
if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( MySessionVar ) )
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: This is what I do, makes it much easier to access session vars in an app. I tend to make classes for the data, and static properties which do all the null check grunt work.

Comment: What if you are storing an object in the Session and not just a string?

Comment: See my answer, the use of generics enables type-safety when storing other objects.

Comment: Excuse me, is the 'Session("' part correct? I'm getting errors.

Comment: It would be in VB. :)  changed to square brackets.

Answer (score 8):

The 'as' notation in c# 3.0 is very clean.  Since all session variables are nullable objects, this lets you grab the value and put it into your own typed variable without worry of throwing an exception.  Most objects can be handled this way.

```
string mySessionVar = Session["mySessionVar"] as string;
```

My concept is that you should pull your Session variables into local variables and then handle them appropriately.  Always assume your Session variables could be null and never cast them into a non-nullable type.

If you need a non-nullable typed variable you can then use TryParse to get that.

```
int mySessionInt;
if (!int.TryParse(mySessionVar, out mySessionInt)){
   // handle the case where your session variable did not parse into the expected type 
   // e.g. mySessionInt = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the easiest way to do this that is clear and easy to read is:

```
 String sVar = (string)(Session["SessionVariable"] ?? "Default Value");
```

It may not be the most efficient method, since it casts the default string value even in the case of the default (casting a string as string), but if you make it a standard coding practice, you find it works for all data types, and is easily readable.

For example (a totally bogus example, but it shows the point):

```
 DateTime sDateVar = (datetime)(Session["DateValue"] ?? "2010-01-01");
 Int NextYear = sDateVar.Year + 1;
 String Message = "The Procrastinators Club will open it's doors Jan. 1st, " +
                  (string)(Session["OpeningDate"] ?? NextYear);
```

I like the Generics option, but it seems like overkill unless you expect to need this all over the place.  The extensions method could be modified to specifically extend the Session object so that it has a "safe" get option like Session.StringIfNull("SessionVar") and Session["SessionVar"] = "myval";  It breaks the simplicity of accessing the variable via Session["SessionVar"], but it is clean code, and still allows validating if null or if string if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

This method also does not assume that the object in the Session variable is a string

```
if((Session["MySessionVariable"] ?? "").ToString() != "")
    //More code for the Code God
```

So basically replaces the null variable with an empty string before converting it to a string since `ToString` is part of the `Object` class

Answer (score 1):

Checking for nothing/Null is the way to do it.

Dealing with object types is not the way to go. Declare a strict type and try to cast the object to the correct type. (And use cast hint or Convert)

```
 private const string SESSION_VAR = "myString";
 string sSession;
 if (Session[SESSION_VAR] != null)
 {
     sSession = (string)Session[SESSION_VAR];
 }
 else
 {
     sSession = "set this";
     Session[SESSION_VAR] = sSession;
 }
```

Sorry for any syntax violations, I am a daily VB'er

Answer (score 1):

Typically I create SessionProxy with strongly typed properties for items in the session.  The code that accesses these properties checks for nullity and does the casting to the proper type.  The nice thing about this is that all of my session related items are kept in one place.  I don't have to worry about using different keys in different parts of the code (and wondering why it doesn't work).  And with dependency injection and mocking I can fully test it with unit tests.  If follows DRY principles and also lets me define reasonable defaults.

```
public class SessionProxy
{
    private HttpSessionState session; // use dependency injection for testability
    public SessionProxy( HttpSessionState session )
    {
       this.session = session;  //might need to throw an exception here if session is null
    }

    public DateTime LastUpdate
    {
       get { return this.session["LastUpdate"] != null
                         ? (DateTime)this.session["LastUpdate"] 
                         : DateTime.MinValue; }
       set { this.session["LastUpdate"] = value; }
    }

    public string UserLastName
    {
       get { return (string)this.session["UserLastName"]; }
       set { this.session["UserLastName"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also like to wrap session variables in properties. The setters here are trivial, but I like to write the get methods so they have only one exit point. To do that I usually check for null and set it to a default value before returning the value of the session variable. 
Something like this:

```
string Name
{
   get 
   {
       if(Session["Name"] == Null)
           Session["Name"] = "Default value";
       return (string)Session["Name"];
   }
   set { Session["Name"] = value; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

in this way it can be checked whether such a key is available

```
if (Session.Dictionary.ContainsKey("Sessionkey"))  --> return Bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .NET 3.5?  Create an IsNull extension method:

```
public static bool IsNull(this object input)
{
    input == null ? return true : return false;
}

public void Main()
{
   object x = new object();
   if(x.IsNull)
   {
      //do your thing
   }
}
```

Comment: That could be written:
public static bool Is(this object input)
{
    return input == null;
}

Comment: You should be careful with extension methods.

Comment: Why should I be careful with extension methods?

Comment: why dont you simply use x == null or x != null ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's a string, you can use the String.IsEmptyOrNull() function.