# Checking session if empty or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, nullreferenceexception, tostring

I want to check that session is null or empty i.e. some thing like this:

```
if(Session["emp_num"] != null)
{

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["emp_num"].ToString()))
            {
                //The code
            }
}
```

---

Or just

```
 if(Session["emp_num"] != null)
    {

       // The code
    }
```

because sometimes when i check only with:

```
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["emp_num"].ToString()))
                {
                    //The code
                }
```

I face the following exception:

> Null Reference exception

Comment: have a look at this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234973/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-a-session-variable-is-null-or-empty-in-c

Comment: Your first check should work and is straightforward. The second check doesn't work because you're trying to convert to a string a null object, and *afterwards* check if it's null.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use this if the session variable emp_num will store a string:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["emp_num"] as string))
 {
                //The code
 }
```

If it doesn't store a string, but some other type, you should just check for null before accessing the value, as in your second example.

Answer (score 12):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["emp_num"] != null)
{
     // code if session is not null
}
```

- if at all above fails.

Comment: This seems to be the most appropriate way of handling a value like that one. Right? Using the string value it suppose to contain does not look clean to me.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check that `Session["emp_num"]` is not `null` before trying to convert it to a string otherwise you will get a null reference exception.

I'd go with your first example - but you could make it slightly more "elegant".

There are a couple of ways, but the ones that springs to mind are:

```
if (Session["emp_num"] is string)
{
}
```

or

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["emp_num"] as string))
{
}
```

This will return null if the variable doesn't exist or isn't a string.

Comment: In newer versions of C# you can give a name to the variable when using is:
`if (Session["emp_num"] is string myString)
{
  // myString will not be null
}`

Answer (score 2):

You should first check if `Session["emp_num"]` exists in the session.

You can ask the session object if its indexer has the `emp_num` value or use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["emp_num"])`

Answer (score 2):

If It is simple Session you can apply `NULL` Check directly `Session["emp_num"] != null`

But if it's a session of a list Item then You need to apply any one of the following option

**Option 1:**

```
if (((List<int>)(Session["emp_num"])) != null && (List<int>)Session["emp_num"])).Count > 0)
 {
 //Your Logic here
 }
```

**Option 2:**

```
List<int> val= Session["emp_num"] as List<int>;  //Get the value from Session.

if (val.FirstOrDefault() != null)
 {
 //Your Logic here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Check if the session is empty or not in C# MVC Version Lower than 5.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["emp_num"] as string))
{
    //cast it and use it
    //business logic
}
```

> Check if the session is empty or not in C# MVC Version Above 5.

```
if(Session["emp_num"] != null)
{
    //cast it and use it
    //business logic
}
```