# i Can't detect whether Session variable exists

Tags: vb.net

Can't detect whether Session variable exists

my code is:

```
if session("something") then end if
```

any way to validate this?

greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is VB.NET:

```
If Not (session("something") Is Nothing) Then
    ' use session("something")
End If
```

Comment: `If Not session` ... ;p

Comment: Don't forget:  `If session("something") IsNot Nothing Then`

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET:

```
If session("whatever") is nothing then
    do something
Else
    do something else
End if
```

Have this code in the Page_Load()

```
if(Session["SessionName"] == null)
{
    //Session Does not Exists
}
else
{
    //Session Exists
}
```

or Refer:

[What is the best way to determine a session variable is null or empty in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234973/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-a-session-variable-is-null-or-empty-in-c)

Comment: The question is tagged VB.NET.