# How to assign Session object to local object in C#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want to how to assign the session variable, which is of the type of a class I have define, Here OrderData class. 
I get error on 'Session["MyOrder"];'

My code snippet it like below.
Also as ord will be a reference to the object, Any change to the object will be reflected to the session object?

```
OrderData ord = new OrderData();  
if (Session["MyOrder"] == null)
{
    Session.Add("MyOrder", ord);
}
else
{
    ord = Session["MyOrder"];
}
```

Comment: *Any change to the object will be reflected to the session object?* Yes, it will reflect. Both point to same reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly cast it to your type like:

```
ord = Session["MyOrder"] as OrderData;
```

and then check for `null`. `as` could return `null` if the casting fails.

```
if(ord != null)
{
   //valid value
}
```

You can also use:

```
ord = (OrderData) Session["MyOrder"];
```

But this could throw an exception in case your `Session` holds a different type than `OrderData`

For:

> Also as ord will be a reference to the object, Any change to the
>   object will be reflected to the session object?

Since `objects are instances of a class, *a reference type*, they will point to the same instance.

Consider the example below:

```
OrderData ord1 = new OrderData() {ID = 2};
Session["MyOrder"] = ord1;

var ord2 = Session["MyOrder"] as OrderData;
ord2.ID = 1;
```

at the end of code execution both `ord1` and `ord2` will have `ID` as `1`, as both references points to the same object.

Comment: if you are worried about throwing an exception then why not do the following to safely check 
`if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["MyOrder"] as string))` ?

Comment: @MethodMan, `MyOrder` is not a string, there is no need to convert it to a string and then check using `String.IsNullOrEmpty`. Casting it against *particular type* using `as` and then checking against `null` is sufficient.

Comment: If you look at the `OP` second line of code in his question what I have commented on is what it was in reference to, prior to your multiple updates to your answer.. the `OP` is checking is the session is null way before adding the Object to the Session

Comment: @MethodMan, Are you saying to use *your* `string.IsNullOrEmpty` check to see if the key exists in the Sesion, instead of this check `if (Session["MyOrder"] == null)` ?

Comment: we had this discussion before..many ways to do this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234973/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-a-session-variable-is-null-or-empty-in-c
cheers