# Testing a session variable for null or empty space

Tags: c#, if-statement

What I currently have is this:

```
if ((string)Session["PlanID"] == null)
{
   string PlanID = Request.QueryString["PlanID"];
   Session["PlanID"] = PlanID;
}
```

What I need is something like this:

```
if ((string)Session["PlanID"] == null) or if ((string)Session["PlanID"] == "")
{
   string PlanID = Request.QueryString["PlanID"];
   Session["PlanID"] = PlanID;
}
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Seems that this question may have already been answered: [What is the best way to determine a session variable is null or empty in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234973/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-a-session-variable-is-null-or-empty-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use IsNullOrEmpty from string.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["PlanID"])) {
   string PlanID = Request.QueryString["PlanID"];
   Session["PlanID"] = PlanID;
}
```

Comment: And, depending on .net version, `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` may be available (and preferable).

Comment: I'd recommend `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` over `IsNullOrEmpty` as it covers more of the "undesirable" spectrum.

Comment: IsNullOrWhitespace may be preferable, but he said "empty space" which is why I answered with IsNullOrEmpty. If you want to check null, "", or "   ", then yes, use IsNullOrWhitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx).

This method also checks for null values

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)Session["PlanID"]))
{
   string PlanID = Request.QueryString["PlanID"];
   Session["PlanID"] = PlanID;
}
```